# A word for untrue innovation/invention/discovery

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

> This company publicized ————— as inventions and discoveries.
>
> What they propose as an invention is just a —————.

I am looking for a word/phrase meaning unfounded view/idea/claim or untrue innovation/discovery.

Answer (score 2):

**Hoax** is a possibility.

Per *Merriam-Webster*, it means:

> something accepted or established by fraud or fabrication

*believes the Loch Ness Monster is a hoax*

Answer (score 1):

> This company publicized **pipedreams** as inventions and discoveries.
> What they propose as an invention is just a **pipedream**.

> **Pipedream** (n.)
>
> An illusory or fantastic plan, hope, or story [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pipe%20dream)

> **Pipe dream** (n.)
>
> An idea or plan that is impossible or very unlikely to happen:
>
> *Her plans are not realistic - they'll never be more than a **pipe dream**.* [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/pipe-dream)

Answer (score 1):

One sense of **phony** fits:

> **phony** [/phoney] [adjective]: 1. not real or genuine; fake; counterfeit
>
> - *a phony diamond*
>
> [• *the phoney war*]
>
> [noun]:
>
> 4. something that is phony; a counterfeit or fake

[[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/phony)]

- *What they claim to be an earth-shattering invention is really just a phony.*